# XAMPP and EPM Agent: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: mysql

I am trying to write back the data from EPM Cloud to phpMyAdmin (XAMPP Server) using Oracle EPM Agent.

So, this is the table in phpMyAdmin.
Table Name: agenttest,
Database Name: test
[image]
and when it comes to privileges in phpMyAdmin:
[image]
I queried plugin status and I think the plugin is fine
[image]
Yet, when I am executing export in Data Management, I am encountering the following error.
[image]
So sorry if my question is vague since I am still a learner and new to this kind of integration. It would be really great if you guys can let me know what access I am missing to provide.

Thank you so much in advance for sharing your ideas! Really means a lot!

Comment: Either your user name and/or password are incorrect

Comment: in phpMyAdmin folder -> config file -> I see that username is root and password is none. I have provided the same in data management. With the same user name and password, I am able to retrieve the data but I am not able to write back.

Comment: According to the error message your password is not blank...